# Can I set Superuser Inside the Launcher?

Tags: launcher

I have a script that I run every time I boot up my laptop (to reset the screen brightness).  I would like to be able to execute this command using a Launcher:

`echo 1500 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

Unfortunately, in order to execute this command (to edit the file) I need to be SU and type in my username and password. I know that UNIX shell scripts are designed such that you can't enter interactive variables like this, but I was hoping the Launcher would have more functionality.

Is it possible to enter interactive arguments like superusername and password in the Launcher? If so, how?

Comment: You can try adding a NOPASSWD entry to `/etc/sudoers` with `visudo` to make it run without a password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using `gksu`. Specifically make the launcher run the command:

```
gksu "bash -c 'echo 1500 > /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness'"
```

This will make the script prompt you for your password and then change the brightness.

Another, better, solution that might or might not work depending on your hardware is to use the gnome-settings Daemon to change brightness. This will allow you to change brightness without needing to enter your password.

The command to do it this way is:

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power --method org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.SetPercentage 100
```

You can replace the `100` at the end with any percentage brightness from 0-100.

As I said this might not work in all cases and should only be used when you are logged in.

In order to get these to be runnable from the launcher you will need to make what is called a desktop file. To do this you should make a new file called `~/.local/share/applications/fullbright.desktop` and copy paste the following into it.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Full Brightness
GenericName=Brightness
Comment=Set Full Brightness
Exec=gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.SettingsDaemon --object-path /org/gnome/SettingsDaemon/Power --method org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power.Screen.SetPercentage 100
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=checkbox
Categories=Utility;
```

If the gdbus command does not work on your system replace it with the gksu one.

You should now be able to call this command from the launcher with the name `Full Brightness` and pin it to your dock like any other program.

Comment: For some reason your first solution (the gksu solution) isn't working.  It looks like it is working fine, but in the end the screen brightness isn't reset like it is if I just SUDO. Can you give me your method for writing this .desktop file?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @theJollySin Sorry. I made a mistake with the `gksu` command but I fixed it now. Really though you should use the `gdbus` one if possible. I have also added a desktop file for it.

Comment: Thank you!  That is a great solution (I went with the gksu method, my laptop has a high-end monitor and I couldn't get the Gnome settings working at all). This is still kind of an ugly work around for an Ubuntu problem, but I'm happy with the result.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I am very surprised to say that I have looked into this brightness issue about 5 different times and somehow never come across this post. (Changing brightness from the graphical menus and from the function keys do not work correctly on my laptop but this does). I think I will write a script and/or desktop launcher that makes it possible to increment/decrement brightness using this command - I'll post it here when I'm done.